# R object not found, although returned using print

Tags: r

I don't understand the R output. It seems that my clearly defined object `outcome` is not found, although it is successfully used in sub-functions and printed. How is that possible?

My R code:

```
f.hazardratio <- function(input)
{
    outcome <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
    category <- c(rep("surv",2),rep("term",2),rep("lobw",2))

    for(i in 1:length(outcome))
        {               
            if(nrow(subset(input,input[,paste("out",category[i],sep=".")]==outcome[i]))>0)
                {
                    lex <- f.lexis(data=input,
                                   out=category[i],
                                   out.case=outcome[i])
                    print(str(lex))
                    print(outcome[i])
                    print(head(subset(lex, lex.Xst=="A")))
                    print(head(subset(lex, lex.Xst==outcome[i])))

# nrow(subset(lex, lex.Xst==outcome[i])) is the value I am actually interest in and causes the same error message as print(), which I only added for identifying the problem
# code continues, but not shown ...

              }
      }
}
```

And the output:

```
 Classes ‘Lexis’ and 'data.frame':  107455 obs. of  6 variables:
  $ pre.time : num
  $ lex.dur : num
  $ lex.Xst : Factor w/ 3 levels
  $ lex.Cst : Factor w/ 3 levels

 [1] "A"

 pre.time lex.dur lex.Xst lex.Cst
 930    145      36  A         vv     
 2255  273      14  A         vv  
 4842  115      99  A         vv  
 5127  260      30  A         vv  
 5217    71    108  A         v    
 5422  152        2  A         vv 

 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) (from #32) : object 'outcome' not found
```

I have already tried to alter the type of variables from factor to character or vice versa and tried to define an intermediate, temporary variable `tmp <- outcome[i]`. Unfortunately, nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Have you tried any alternative types of subsetting, for example `xy <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = letters[1:10]);mysub <- c("a", "b", "c");xy[xy$y %in% mysub, ]`?

Comment: What is the problem? You don't have access to `Lex` outside of your function or you are unsure of why `print(outcome[i])` is False? `exists("string")` checks if the evaluated string exists. The variables `"A", "B"...."F"` indeed doesn't exist, but your code should work fine.

Comment: The problem is the fifth print statement in the loop where `lex` is in scope. `outcome[i]` is "A", subsetting with "A" explicitly works, subsetting with `outcome[i]` (which has just printed as "A") doesn't.

Comment: Using the intermediate variable `tmp`, the correct syntax is `print(exists("tmp"))` and not `print(exists(tmp))`.

Comment: `exists(outcome[i])` returns FALSE because its testing if "A" exists rather than if `outcome[i]` exists. Its a red herring to the overall problem.

Comment: I've just duplicated your code structure and done my best to write the missing functions and guess the missing data and I can't get subset to barf. Given your code has *at least one* missing closing curly bracket I'm guessing we're wasting time here. `subset` can create scoping issues (which is why I like to be explicit and use square brackets) but you've not given us enough to reproduce.

Comment: Yes, as Spacedman wrote, the problem is that subsetting with outcome[i], the element of a character vector, is not working, while subsetting directly with "A" works. I will try the explicit way and use square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `subset()` using square brackets as suggested by Spacedman solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to functional programming. If you want to specify a particular value that will be returned, then wrap it in the `return(.)` function. Otherwise the value returned is simple the results of the last evaluation. All of the variables created within the function will be inaccessible from outside and later garbage-collected. Calling `print` may or may not give you exactly the object. Some authors pass the object-to-be-printed on to `summary.class` (where class is an attribute of the object)  first and do not return an exact copy of the argument.